# How to connect with MySql in GWT? (AppEngine)

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, gwt, connection

I've strange problem. 
I'm using GWT on AppEngine and I want to create RPC which connect to MySql. All this day I'm sitting on it.. This is my implementation of RPC methods:

```
java.sql.Connection con = null;
    public DataBaseServiceImpl() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.print("bladd..");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8806/base";
     try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection( url,"root", "");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String[]> getTables(int idUser) throws SQLException {

         Statement st =  con.createStatement();
         ResultSet retrive = st.executeQuery("query");
         ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
         while(retrive.next())
         {
             String[] s = new String[2];
             int theInt= retrive.getInt("ID__TABLE");
             String str = retrive.getString("LABEL");
             s[0]=Integer.toString(theInt);
             s[1]=str;
             result.add(s);
         }
        return result;
    }
```

And I have this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unable to initialize driver properties due to
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime can not
>   access a member of class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl with
>   modifiers "private"

I don't have any idea what it is.
Could someone help me?

Regards.

Comment: That's only implementation of class which extends from RemoteServiceServlet and implements DataBaseService.

Answer (score 0):

Well the bottom line is you have really messy code.  There are many violations to good coding practice.

From the code you included this line never gets executed:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection( url,"root", "");
```

So there is no connection to your db.  Does your exception indicate that this line

```
Statement st =  con.createStatement();
```

is the problem?

Comment: You are right.. I change that to this:<code> java.sql.Connection con = null;
 public DataBaseServiceImpl() {
  try {
   String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8806/base";
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   con = DriverManager.getConnection( url,"root", "");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   System.out.print("bladd.."+e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
</code> But it still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running on jre1.7.0_25.
I resolved it by upgrading to jre1.7.0_45.